# Understanding documentation of React with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently reading the documentation about react and redux:

https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/5502940e7f139bb88bf0b67fcb838a7e3de3be6c/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.md

There, specifically in the code example here:

https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/5502940e7f139bb88bf0b67fcb838a7e3de3be6c/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.md#containersfilterlinkjs

you can see this line:

```
dispatch(setVisibilityFilter(ownProps.filter))
```

Now my question is, where does the 'filter' property in ownProps come from? Can somebody explain to me, where the connection is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the call to filterlink.

```js
components/Footer.js

import React from 'react'
import FilterLink from '../containers/FilterLink'

const Footer = () => (
  <p>
    Show:
    {" "}
    <FilterLink filter="SHOW_ALL">
      All
    </FilterLink>
    {", "}
    <FilterLink filter="SHOW_ACTIVE">
      Active
    </FilterLink>
    {", "}
    <FilterLink filter="SHOW_COMPLETED">
      Completed
    </FilterLink>
  </p>
)

export default Footer
```

Answer (score 0):

ownProps are the props that were passed directly to the component by the React render call of the component's parent. In this case, the component in question is FilterLink. The FilterLinks are being passed a filter prop by the render method of its parent, [Footer.js](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/5502940e7f139bb88bf0b67fcb838a7e3de3be6c/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.md#componentsfooterjs). e.g.

```
<FilterLink filter="SHOW_ALL">
  All
</FilterLink>
```